# why most applications are precompiled?

Tags: cpu, operating-systems, compile

It confused me since I began to build a PC. Games and applications are given as binary executable files, but how can I fully utilize my CPU's advanced instruction sets. There must be difference between Intel and AMD CPUs, but on the download page they only care about your operating system. Do operating system provide an abstraction layer for all specs?

Comment: To compile a big application such as a game or web browser can take hours or days to compile and optimise. Would you be happy spending 6-10 hours to download all the code and assets for something and then spend another day with your computer acting like a 1000W space heater compiling all the programs, libraries and other code?  On top of that all the code is company proprietary information, if you made a game would you really want some dude on the street rewriting it however they liked to remove your revenue streams?

Comment: I forget the source code will be an issue. But what I really want to know is why the publisher doesn't care about your CPU, like user can use CPU ranging from 10 years ago to nowadays.

Comment: What makes you think they don't? Most games already list a minimum CPU and operating system requirements and that means that the developer can set that as the minimum CPU they optimise for. They still need to target the largest user-base they can. Past that there is always the possibility of having optimised code for specific CPUs if required and it is worth the effort and loading specific optimised libraries or blocks of code based on the current CPU. Nothing is stopping that from happening, except it not being worth that effort for a small performance boost.

Comment: emm... sorry for my shallow understanding of compiling. I don't know how to describe the question. Maybe why they can provide a unique solution to all types of CPUs. The CPUs are evolving but you only target one CPU as compiled solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There must be difference between Intel and AMD CPUs

There is very little. All 64-bit Intel CPUs essentially use the "AMD64" instruction set, with only minor differences between AMD64 and Intel's EM64T.

(Sure, the *actual* underlying architecture is completely different, but the microcode hides all of it from the outside view. The only thing the OS sees is the x86 or AMD64 instructions.)

While newer CPUs often support more instructions than older ones, even within the same base architecture, often the difference only really matters for specific cases so software can be built to automatically use the best variant. (For example, TLS libraries will auto-detect whether the system has support for AES instructions)

AMD64 itself was actually built out of Intel's own 32-bit "x86" instruction set and still falls under "Intel architecture" as a general term. (AMD has been building Intel-compatible CPUs as early as Am486.)

Intel did try to create a wholly new 64-bit architecture, Itanium (IA64), but it sank.

Other incompatible architectures do exist, with Arm64 being the most prominent one, and yes, lack of binary executables for those is often a problem.

> Do operating system provide an abstraction layer for all specs?

Generally speaking, they don't.

But there are specific cases where they **do** – e.g. Apple's macOS did automatic translation for old PowerPC binaries when running on Intel CPUs, and now it does automatic translation for Intel binaries when running on Apple Silicon (which is Arm64).

Similarly, Windows used to provide x86 emulation on Alpha, and now it provides [x86 and Arm32 emulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/arm/apps-on-arm-x86-emulation) on Arm64.

Linux doesn't emulate anything by default, especially as most software can be recompiled (distributions often build packages for quite a few architectures), but it does have "qemu-user" available for various architectures.

Finally, programs that are built on "bytecode" platforms such as .NET or Java are more or less cross-architecture by default.